# C++ Project Types for 3D Modelling and Game Control Program

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am a freshman programmer. I am trying to develop control software for a VR controller. It will use data from an array of rotary potentiometers to move a wireframe. The modeling software will apply textures and set the collision mask. These two programs are meant to be as fast as possible while running, integrate directly into games, and if possible exist as one program. I am using Visual Studio 2019 and was wondering which project type I should use.

Edit 1: I should clarify that this will be a game development tool. 1 part of it will only be used in the game and the other will be used to develop controls and create character skins and textures. The platform this will be used on is Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could try to use [DirectX](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/zh-hans/vs/features/directx-game-dev/?rr=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F) for 3D game development. You could create a windows desktop application or a UWP application.

To build DirectX desktop games, choose the “Game development with C++” workload under the “Mobile & Gaming” category.

[image]

To build a DirectX desktop app, you can start with the Win32 Project template in the New Project dialog, or download a [Win32 game template](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates), or download a sample from [DirectX11 samples](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples) or [DirectX12 samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples) as a starting point.

You could also build a DirectX game for UWP.

For more details I suggest you could refer to the link:https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/directx-game-development-with-c-in-visual-studio/

Answer (score 0):

you should use Empty Project if you want to run your program in windows command prompt. if you want to run it like any other windows software with graphical interface then you need to use Windows Desktop Application.

[image]

according to me you should use empty project for this program.